# Why does Qt include empty class definitions of existing classes in the header files?

Tags: c++, qt

I am reading through the examples on the Qt page and am wondering why they add references to already existing classes in their code [example](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.1/network-http-httpwindow-h.html):

```
#ifndef HTTPWINDOW_H
#define HTTPWINDOW_H

#include <QDialog>

class QFile;
class QHttp;
class QHttpResponseHeader;
class QLabel;
class QLineEdit;
class QProgressDialog;
class QPushButton;

class HttpWindow : public QDialog
{
...
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Those are forward declarations. Using them can (in some cases) obviate the need to #include the relevant header files, thus speeding up compilation. The Standard C++ library does something similar with the `<iosfwd>` header.

Answer (score 9):

This is called [Forward Declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration)

You can refer to [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-to-use-forward-declaration) to have a detailed idea of when to use Forward Declaration

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, this is simply a forward declaration.  And in the header file these classes will typically be used via pointers so a full declaration of the class is not needed until the .cpp.  So, e.g. your header might continue...

```
class HttpWindow : public QDialog
{

QFile *m_pFile;
QHttp *m_pHttp;
...
}
```